# Laravel server side chart generation

Tags: php, laravel, charts, cron

I am using PHP 5.6 and Laravel 5.3. I want to implement server-side chart generation that can be stored in storage folder(optional requirement, but highly preferred) by passing the data to it, and finally mailing it to users on the laravel scheduler. I want to do it on the cronjob, but I am unable to find a proper plugin for this, usually what I get is client-side chart generation, which can be converted to a screenshot and then mailed,but I am looking for a complete server-side chart generation, converting it into a JPEG or PDF and store it in the server or mail it as an attachment. I want something similar to Grammarly mail, which includes charts too. Any plugins for laravel or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at [pChart](https://github.com/szymach/c-pchart), it allows you to generate charts server side and store the output as images. From there you can just use the Laravel [Mail](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mail) functionality to send your mail.

Comment: Thanks, @liamjnorman  I will surely give it a try. I just now implemented [WannaCharts](http://wannacharts.com/) and that too seems fine with my current requirement. The only thing that bothers me is regarding the Integrity of their service. Hope so they support long-term and no data infringement occurs.

Comment: Any ideas on where to extract the pcharts contents into the laravel directory?

Comment: Also does pchart support multiple datasets in one graph?

Comment: Got my solutions !! Pcharts works well. Now I am able to render charts on the fly.